# ReactJS: How to read and write to a file

Tags: reactjs

I have a file `config.js` which contain various objects and arrays. It is a large file so i decided to keep it as a separate file. I want to read this array called `Config.EmojiCategorySpritesheetDimens` from my `config.js` file in a component file called `TextDisplay.js`. How could this be done using React or React-Redux. Please help

config.js

```
var Config = {};
Config.Emoji = {
"00a9": ["\u00A9", ["copyright"]],
"00ae": ["\u00AE", ["registered"]],
"203c": ["\u203C", ["bangbang"]],
"2049": ["\u2049", ["interrobang"]],
"2122": ["\u2122", ["tm"]],
...etc
}

Config.EmojiCategorySpritesheetDimens = [
[7, 27],
[4, 29],
[7, 33],
[3, 34],
[7, 34]
];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "read"? Did you try to [require & export](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1)?

Comment: Yeah i imported the file `import config from './config'` but the array in `config.js` aint available to me. How can i make the array in `config.js` to be availabe to me. I mean how to export the array from `config.js`? So tht i'll import it in my `TextDisplay.js`

Comment: I'll edit the Title as per it is done in react. I'm really new to React. I know its a silly title

Comment: React is library for view (DOM). Your question is completely out of React scope

Comment: @iofjuupasli I want to render the array elements as list-items in my component's div. So how could I do it? I dont want my comopnent file to be bulky. What could be the best practice then? Help is appreciated

Comment: write a file on the client-side using a client-side script is not good for security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using module.export, I succeed reading the table:

```
var Config = {};
Config.Emoji = {
"00a9": ["\u00A9", ["copyright"]],
"00ae": ["\u00AE", ["registered"]],
"203c": ["\u203C", ["bangbang"]],
"2049": ["\u2049", ["interrobang"]],
"2122": ["\u2122", ["tm"]]
}

Config.EmojiCategorySpritesheetDimens = [
[7, 27],
[4, 29],
[7, 33],
[3, 34],
[7, 34]
];

module.exports = Config;
```

result:
[image]

config.js is then available in all the component defined in TextDisplay.js