# How to save/store and display a react-webcam image?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, storage, webcam

I'm trying to build a project that uses react-webcam and getScreenshot() to take a "selfie" using the code from the Capture Image section on [this website](https://blog.openreplay.com/capture-real-time-images-and-videos-with-react-webcam/). Below is what the webcam component returns:

```
<div className="Container">
        {img === null ? (
          <>
            <Webcam
              audio={false}
              mirrored={true}
              height={400}
              width={400}
              ref={webcamRef}
              screenshotFormat="image/png"
              videoConstraints={videoConstraints}
            />
            <button onClick={capture}>Capture photo</button>
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <img src={img} alt="screenshot" />
            <Link to="/gallery" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                <p>new gallery</p>
            </Link>
            <button onClick={() => setImg(null)}>Retake</button>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
```

Right now the selfie only displays on the same page that the capture takes place on, but I want it to be displayed on a different page in this app and not disappear once I restart the app or refresh the page. I also want to be able to delete an image if desired.

For above reasons I'm considering using firestore (which we used for storing & uploading text only in a class last semester) but I have no idea the proper steps to do that for image since I know it's different and my professor didn't go over how to do that.

I tried importing the image url variables from the page with the webcam capture (import imgURl from "...") to my gallery page in different ways but I would either get the webcam itself in the gallery or no image at all. I don't think I'm grasping how to export the image that was just captured into another page.

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61862108/13546426) to get a `blob` from the image captured with `react-webcam`. Next, save the `blob` to the user's file-system with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66079045/13546426) snippet of code.