# Writing data from form to local JSON file with React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Is it possible to write collected data from form to local JSON file with React? If yes can anyone give a good example, if no can you give a good alternative?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491710/can-reactjs-write-into-file/49491783).

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to create a new file, one option is to make a downloadable link as shown below. You can even do it programatically

```
function App() {
  const jsonData = { age: 12, name: "Someone" };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <a
        href={
          "data:text/json;charset=utf-8," +
          encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(jsonData))
        }
        download="fileName.json"
      >
        Download JSON
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}
```