# How to code to send array data to disk with JSON file in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I am a student who study ReactJS and a beginner. I am studying 'To Do' app example(I think it is a famous sample for react study in web) using React Class Component. I don't know server side programming yet. I want to write the array data as a JSON file in my pc's C:/, but I cannot find some example or study material. Is it impossible without node.js, express and DBMS ?? Please, help me. (My English is not very good enough to explain. I am sorry)

Comment: could be duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491710/can-reactjs-write-into-file

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible without nodejs or express to make api request. Use
`json-server` library. Here is a [link](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) to this library.

Comment: Thanks for your useful information.^^ Also, I need some sample codes how to send an array data in my App.js to json-server. please, help me.

Comment: contact me via email jasurkurbanov96@gmail.com