# npm exceljs is unable to read any existing file

Tags: reactjs, excel, web, npm, exceljs

```
// read from a file
const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
await workbook.xlsx.readFile(filename);
// ... use workbook
```

**As per the exceljs documentation, it should load the already existing file 'filename', but when I tried reading it,**

```
const sheet = workbook.addWorksheet('My Sheet');
```

sheet was actually undefined.

**My concern is, is it possible to do read from and write to a file operations in ReactJS, also I came across another article**

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491710/can-reactjs-write-into-file#:~:text=React%20runs%20in%20browser%20so,gets%20served%20to%20the%20browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491710/can-reactjs-write-into-file#:%7E:text=React%20runs%20in%20browser%20so,gets%20served%20to%20the%20browser)

**that suggest it is not possible**

Answer (score 0):

My project did read and write on the same file template using exceljs in node js. Hope can help you.

```
workbook.xlsx.readFile(template)
  .then(function () {
    // machines
    var wsMachine = workbook.getWorksheet('No');
    wsTemplate = _.cloneDeep(wsMachine);
    for (var index = 1; index <= 10; index++) {
      var copySheet = workbook.addWorksheet('No' + index, { state: 'visible' });
      copySheet.pageSetup.printArea = 'A1:FE219';
      var ws = _.cloneDeep(wsTemplate);
      copySheet.model = Object.assign(ws.model, {
        mergeCells: ws.model.merges
      });
      copySheet.name = 'No' + index;
    }

    wsMachine.state = 'hidden';
    wsTemplate.state = 'hidden';
    return workbook.xlsx.writeFile(urlOutput);
  })
  .then(function () {
    return true
  })
  .catch(function () {
    return false;
  });
```

Happy code